# Getting an error when trying to migrate to DV server from Grid with Media Temple

Tags: database, errors, installation, migration

Trying to migrate my wordpress site... getting this error:

```
PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant DATABASE_SERVER - assumed 'DATABASE_SERVER' in /usr/share/plesk-wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(996) : eval()'d code on line 31 PHP Notice: Undefined index: DATABASE_SERVER in /usr/share/plesk-wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(996) : eval()'d code on line 31 {&quot;err_code&quot;:0,&quot;err_message&quot;:&quot;Error establishing a database connection&quot;} PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /var/www/vhosts/gunprime.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1367 Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /var/www/vhosts/gunprime.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1367
```

Folowing directions from this site https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204644950/migrate-to-a-dv-from-a-grid

I have uploaded the content and imported the old database.

Can you help me get it working?

Comment: Please ask hosting support about hosting problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to update info in the wp-config.php file to match the new 
    DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST

Comment: Glad that you solved your question. May you click the checkmark next to your answer to indicate that this issue is solved?